# alert doesn't work in packaged apps

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webview, google-chrome-app

I'm studying webview in packaged apps of chrome and I'm studying browser sample from chrome. 
in browser.js file in onload function, I added alert("webview apps"); at the first row and the code didn't work anymore, when I deleted this row, it worked again.

```
onload = function() {
    alert("webview app");
    var webview = document.querySelector('webview');
    doLayout();
    ...
}
```

so does alert work on packaged apps? 

P/s: console.log also doesn't work, I saw the source code use it, but nothing is displayed on inspect element window

Comment: *"alert doesn't work in packaged apps"* **Good!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Console.log *should* work, it all depends on what view you are looking at.  For example to get to the logs when in a window, you have to "Inspect Element" on the page to get to it.

Alert has [been disabled](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated.html) along with confirm and a number of other legacy web features.

Comment: when open the apps, I do left click on the new window and choose inspect element but the nothing is displayed on the console?

Comment: so how to enable alert, do I have to add alert into permissions?

Comment: no, the API is removed.  Can you share an example with me so I can check.  I am looking at my code now and console.log is working fine.

Comment: when I click on webview part that loads the google page, I see the error but not console from the browser.js
here is the picture
http://i182.photobucket.com/albums/x38/DNK90/canary-dev-tool.jpg
the code is the newest code that i've downloaded from chrome, I just delete the minimum version and I'm using chrome canary

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like debugging. And if you want to debug a packaged app, the Developer Tools should be enough to replace `alert` (and other dialogs). But the Developer Tools are not enabled by default. You can enable it on the `chrome://flags/#debug-packed-apps`.

Check this out [this blog post](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/enabling-chrome-developer-tools-inside-postman/) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your package app to run in a sandboxed mode, but this will not allow access to any of the api's that manipulate the page.

http://developer.chrome.com/apps/sandboxingEval.html

This will essentially allow the app to run in its own environment allowing you to view the app as you have programmed it.  This is done for security of creating apps.  Console.log works perfect.  When you go to inspect element and then select console in the inspect element view you should see any "echo" results you wanted printed.