# window.alert() is not available in packaged apps

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I am making a Chrome application. I keep getting the error in console:

```
window.alert() is not available in packaged apps. extensions::platformApp:17
```

Line 17 of that file is just a line of code to log the error to the console. Is there a way to alert the user of an event in a chrome app (like this [image](http://de.asciicasts.com/system/photos/344/original/E205I02.png)?)Is it because I have adblock installed in Firefox (I don't use Chrome)? I thought alert() was pretty basic.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [alert doesn't work in packaged apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798706/alert-doesnt-work-in-packaged-apps)

Comment: Definite duplicate, but the answer on this post is better IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `alert` function has been disabled in Chrome packaged apps, because it halts the execution of Javascript and thus provides a poor user experience. For development purposes you should use `console.log` and for user facing interactions you should use a HTML based dialog.

Comment: ...such as the dialog element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own synchronous alert/prompt with a function that waits for a jQuery promise before completion and then when the user clicks the "OK" button resolves the promise. Then when ever you replace your "alert" with "myCustomAlert" you have to declare the function it's called in as an "async function" and then "await" before the call.

This may sound complicated but if you play with it in JSFiddle it's quite simple.

I found this useful if you are porting over an app where you can't break the function up into different sections very easily. This does requires the jQuery library.

Here is my example https://jsfiddle.net/littlej247/g4k2h56c/5/

```
//*****HTML*********

<button type="button" id="alertMe">Alert ME!</button>

<div id="backgroudDiv">  <!-- This is optional but I like to grey out the background -->
  <div id="alertDiv">
    <b><span id="alertTitle"></span></b>
    <br />
    <span id="alertText"></span>
    <hr>
    <button type="button" id="alertDone">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>

//Remember JS can't run in HTML files on chrome apps so functions are called by DOM
document.getElementById("alertMe").onclick = async function () {
  console.log("Starting function \n Processing a bunch of stuff, calculating variable(s)....");
  await myCustomAlert("Alert Title Here","Message");
  console.log("Continue processing stuff with the variable(s) after the alert is clicked.... \n function finished");
};


//*****JavaScript*********

//Alerts can not be used in chrome apps, myCustomAlert function is a replacement.
var alertPromise
function myCustomAlert(messageTitle,messageBody){ 
  console.log("myCustomAlert has been called");
  alertPromise = $.Deferred();

  document.getElementById("alertTitle").textContent=messageTitle;
  document.getElementById("alertText").textContent=messageBody;
  document.getElementById('backgroudDiv').style.display='block';

  return $.when(alertPromise).done();
}

document.getElementById("alertDone").onclick = function () {
  console.log("Finally, User clicked Done, \n now we can get back to work..");
  document.getElementById('backgroudDiv').style.display='none';
    alertPromise.resolve();
    return(false);
};

//*****Styles*********

#alertDiv { 
  width: 400px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 100px auto auto auto;
  z-index: 10000;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
 }
#backgroudDiv { 
  display: none; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 9000; 
  left: 0; 
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
 }
```